# Combine two MySql into one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sql queries that I need to combine into one query for better efficiency, just not sure how to do it. Basically I need to query my Supplier, then for each supplier check to see if the Listing table has more than one record that matches based upon "supplier id", if it does then I need to return the supplier name and id. Here are my two queries:

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT          s.name, s.id 
FROM            Supplier s
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT      l.asin, 
            l.id, 
            COUNT(*) c
FROM        Listing l
LEFT JOIN   Product p
 ON         p.id = l.product_id
LEFT JOIN   Supplier s
 ON         p.supplier_id = s.id 
WHERE       (l.matchValidated IS NULL OR l.matchValidated = 0)
AND         s.id = SUPPLIER_ID_GOES_HERE
GROUP BY    l.asin HAVING c > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have supplier joined in the second query so you just need to add the supplier name and id to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT      l.asin, 
            l.id,
            s.name AS supplier_name,
            s.id AS supplier_id, 
            COUNT(*) c
FROM        Listing l
LEFT JOIN   Product p
 ON         p.id = l.product_id
LEFT JOIN   Supplier s
 ON         p.supplier_id = s.id 
WHERE       (l.matchValidated IS NULL OR l.matchValidated = 0)
GROUP BY    l.asin, l.id, s.name, s.id 
HAVING      c > 1;
```